# Why is this a complete sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence

"Another organization, the International Writing Program at the University of Iowa, offers writers from around the world a three-month residency in which **to** share not only stories and poems but also the experience of navigating a new environment."

Specifically, I am having problems with the bolded "to", which I feel should be replaced by "they". Can someone clarify why this is a full sentence - I am having difficulty visualizing it.

Comment: Thank you so much! For this sentence, would the second part be: a three month residency [to share in] not only ... but also ... environment?

Comment: *A chair in which to sit* = *a chair to sit in*, *a desk at which to work* = *a desk to work at*, *a space in which to read* = *a space to read in*. If you replaced *to* with *they can*, the meaning wouldn't really change, but the syntax would be different and the register a bit less formal.